# Showing PDF on Touch Scroll in android

Tags: android, pdf

I have multiple one paged PDF in my SD-Card in Android mobile. I want to view it from my application but don't know how to show it.

I can use any jar to display it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to hand off the viewing of the PDF to another application such as Adobe Reader.

Using an Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File pdf = new File(FILE_LOCATION);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdf), "application/pdf");
startActivity(i);
```

We should also account for the scenario where the user does not have a PDF reader available:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File pdf = new File(FILE_LOCATION);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdf), "application/pdf");

List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if(!list.isEmpty()){
    startActivity(i);   
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "A PDF reader is required to open this.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First u install the acrobat reader in ur emulator and the u view ur pdf file in emulator.
Download acrobat reader apk and install in emulator using this command from command line.
1. Go to start and open run.
2. type cmd and type "adb -e install FilePath" press enter.
Then u go to ur application and write this code for viewing pdf in acrobat reader.
```

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File pdf = new File(<File name whit full path>);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdf), "application/pdf");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: How to use scroll activity to view next page of PDF in intent

Comment: when pdf view activity start it show in acrobat reader. in that view u scroll and view all the pages in file. All pages of file open.